# Filter data /Disregard null value when filtering in Django

Tags: python, django, object, filter

Does anybody know how can I filter data even the passing value is False, it so hassle to make lot of conditions I think there is a way to filter data even the value is false or empty.

[image]

> views.py

```
def sample(request):
    if request.method=='POST':  
  
      province = request.POST.get('province', False)
      municipality = request.POST.get('municipality', False)
      barangay = request.POST.get('barangay', False)
      status = request.POST.get('stats', False)
      batch= request.POST.get('Pbatch', False)
      it_batch= request.POST.get('Itbatch', False)

      filter= Person.objects.filter(province=province, municipality=municipality, 
      barangay=barangay,status=status,batch=batch,it_batch=it_batch)

      return render .. so on and so on...
```

> The problem is when some data has no value or let say false it didn't recognize the data filter, is there any solution or idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you looked at using https://django-filter.readthedocs.io, which will handle most of that kind of logic, such as ignoring a field if no value is passed.

Comment: @Andrew Backer thanks for your response which part in the documentation  you send should I look?

Comment: I'd start with the 'getting started' section, see if it applies to you

Comment: @AndrewBacker It doesn't work :/