# Condition inside objects filter Django

Tags: python, django, post

Im been wondering if it is possible to put condition inside query just like this

```
 sample = Person.objects.filter(province=province, municipality=municipality, if barangay!=None: then 
 barangay ="value")
```

Im been having a problem same with this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64893544/14517031) but I don't know how I can ignore empty value in query. Is there any expert can help me please

Comment: You can use the `if...` clasue

Comment: @ArakkalAbu thanks for your response, Can you give me more detail,  I think you mean I must put condition outside filter?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
barangay_value = "value" if barangay != None else "some other value"

sample = Person.objects.filter(
    province=province, 
    municipality=municipality,
    barangay=barangay_value
)
```

Comment: Yes, but I want the condition inside the filter just like this `bene = Person.objects.filter(province=province, municipality=municipality,if barangay!=None else barangay ="value")` but it didn't work

Comment: Try putting that if expression inside a variable. Let me know if this works! Also, ensure you make explicit where that value is being pointed to inside the QuerySet (e.g. barangay= value)

Comment: did you mean just like this ? [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9wE3.png)  but this is not what Im looking for :/

Comment: thanks for your response but I have value from my database [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0s723.png) if the value is none all the barangays should filter and if theres a value it should filter those selected value

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below

```
sample = Person.objects.filter(province=province, municipality=municipality)
if barangay is not None:
   sample.filter(barangay =barangay)
```

Since Django queries are evaluated lazily that would generate only one query.